# Append several (unequal) 1xn arrays into one large nxm array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I want to subdivide one array into a few smaller ones, they contain the start and stop information of several peaks and need to be saved in separate chunks

```
peaks = np.array([])
subpeak = np.array([])

for i in range(len(stop)):
    for j in range(int(stop[i]-start[i]+20)):
        k = j+start[i]-10
        subpeak = np.append(subpeak,[voltage[k]])
    peaks = np.hstack((peaks, [subpeak]))
    subpeak = np.array([])
```

Now this should give me an array which is len(stop) wide, with every element being the size of k.

So example

```
0 0 0 0
1 3 5 6
3 4 5 6
1 4 5 6
1   3 6
    6
```

As the array and every column as an element. np.append does not seem to work, nor does np.concatenate

Comment: As far as I know you can't have ragged arrays in a numpy array. So you'd need to set the 'empty' values to something like NaN or maintain a mask of where the actual values are (or off course not use a numpy array). See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy

Comment: You could also make it as an array of objects, or add it to a list. The ideal solution would depend on what you're gonna do further with the data.