# TypeError manipulating array in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following string in a seperate .txt file:

```
L#$KJ#()JSEFS(DF)(SD*F
#KJ$H#K$JH@#K$JHD)
SF SDFLKJ#{P@$OJ{SDPFODS{PFO{
#K$HK#JHSFHD(*SHF)SF{HP
#L$H@”#$H”@#L$KH#”@L$K
#~L$KJ#:$SD)FJ)S(DJF)(S
#$KJH#$ 
SDLKFJD(FJ)SDJFSDLFKS 
~L#$KJ:@LK$#J$ 
LSJDF(S*JDF(*SJDF(*J(DSF*J
```

I have to take every element by column position and output how many times in a column an element occurs. For example, Position: 0 or Column 1 ( S: 20.0% #: 50.0% L: 20.0% ~: 10.0%  )

I have written this script in python using NumPy to create an array of arrays by line but am getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Here is the script when I try to print the first column:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

target = open(filename, 'r')

y = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    y.append(np.array(list(target.readline())))

print y[:,1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like the rows are all the same length.  If that's the case, arrays aren't going to help.  I'd suggest treating it as a list of strings, and doing list loops, comprehensions, and string indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`y[:, 1]` is syntatic sugar for `y[(slice(None, None, None), 1)]` which makes it more obvious that you're trying to pass a `tuple` to `y.__getitem__`.

Since `y` is a `list`, that doesn't work<sup>1</sup>

Perhaps you meant:

```
y[:1]
```

which picks out the first two items?

<sup><sup>1</sup>  (It *does* work with properly dimensioned `numpy.ndarray` which might be causing your confusion)</sup>

Comment: How do I access the columns then?

Comment: @rahul2001 -- It's a list, there _are_ no columns.  If there was a consistent number of elements per row, then you could make it a numpy array and all would be OK . . .BUT, you don't satisfy that constraint.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Okay thanks -- so that means I need to add a null element or something per row in order to satisfy the number of elements required to create a numpy array? Is there a way to  create a matrix that can autofill missing elements?

Comment: As far as I know, no function exists to do this.  but it shouldn't be too hard to write your own.  Depending on your application, perhaps masked arrays would be helpful?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14916455/748858

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your text, `txt`, I can split it into lines, and use `zip(*lines)` to rearrange them into 'columns'.  Since the lines vary in length, I'll use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
lines = txt.splitlines()
[l for l in itertools.izip_longest(*lines)]
```

producing:

```
[('L', '#', 'S', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S', '~', 'L'),
 ('#', 'K', 'F', 'K', 'L', '~', '$', 'D', 'L', 'S'),
 ('$', 'J', ' ', '$', '$', 'L', 'K', 'L', '#', 'J'),
 ...
 (None, None, 'O', None, 'K', None, None, None, None, None),
 (None, None, '{', None, None, None, None, None, None, None)]
```

Or if I specify a '_' fillvalue:

```
X=[l for l in itertools.izip_longest(*lines, fillvalue=' ')]

[('L', '#', 'S', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S', '~', 'L'),
 ('#', 'K', 'F', 'K', 'L', '~', '$', 'D', 'L', 'S'),
 ('$', 'J', ' ', '$', '$', 'L', 'K', 'L', '#', 'J'),
 ('K', '$', 'S', 'H', 'H', '$', 'J', 'K', '$', 'D'),
 ('J', 'H', 'D', 'K', '@', 'K', 'H', 'F', 'K', 'F'),
 ...
 (' ', ' ', 'P', ' ', 'L', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'J'),
 (' ', ' ', 'F', ' ', '$', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
 (' ', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'K', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
 (' ', ' ', '{', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')]
```

or as a list of equal length strings:

```
[''.join(x) for x in X]
```

or as an array of characters (29 x 10):

```
np.array(X)

array([['L', '#', 'S', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S', '~', 'L'],
       ['#', 'K', 'F', 'K', 'L', '~', '$', 'D', 'L', 'S'],
       ['$', 'J', ' ', '$', '$', 'L', 'K', 'L', '#', 'J'],
       ...
       [' ', ' ', '{', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

You could do your frequency count on each tuple, string or row.