# Merging Different Dimension or Column of String Using Vstack Python

Tags: python-2.7

This is a continuation from previous question. How to use vstack for the different dimension or column from these example.

```
File : "new.dat"
WBGG 120200Z VRB03KT 030V170 9000 FEW015 BKN160 28/25 Q1013 NOSIG

File : "old.dat"
WBGG 120130Z VRB02KT 9000 FEW015 BKN150 27/25 Q1013 NOSIG    
WBGG 120100Z VRB02KT 9999 FEW014 BKN150 26/25 Q1012 NOSIG
```

Script used as suggested by @Anton vBR as follows but it only works for similar dimension.

```
a = np.loadtxt('old.dat', dtype='object')
b = np.loadtxt('new.dat', dtype='object')

c = np.vstack((b,a))

np.savetxt('old.dat', c, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Expected output is:

```
WBGG 120200Z VRB03KT 030V170 9000 FEW015 BKN160 28/25 Q1013 NOSIG
WBGG 120130Z VRB02KT 9000 FEW015 BKN150 27/25 Q1013 NOSIG    
WBGG 120100Z VRB02KT 9999 FEW014 BKN150 26/25 Q1012 NOSIG
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy)

Comment: @JohnZwinck..I did try using the method but still the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to homogenize the widths first:

```
a = np.loadtxt('old.dat', dtype='object', ndmin=2)
b = np.loadtxt('new.dat', dtype='object', ndmin=2)

a_width = a.shape[1]
b_width = b.shape[1]
if a_width < b_width:
    a = np.append(a, np.zeros((len(a), b_width - a_width), 'S0'), axis=1) # 'U0' in Python 3
if b_width < a_width:
    b = np.append(b, np.zeros((len(b), a_width - b_width), 'S0'), axis=1)
```

Then it will work.

Note that I added `ndmin=2` when loading the files, because otherwise a single-line file produces a 1D array instead of 2D.

Comment: ..thanks for the suggestion however the result still showing " wrong number at column at line 8"..

Comment: @Azam: OK, I reworked it and tested it so it is complete and production ready now.

Comment: @JohnZwinck..sir!, I am trying to figure it out why it still wont work. may be because of python version or what..now still showing same result as above..thanks again for the brilliant efforts..