# How to convert array from dtype=object to dtype=np.int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Currently, the array I got is

```
arr = array([array([ 2,  7,  8, 12, 14]), array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  9, 10]),
   array([0, 1]), array([11, 13])], dtype=object)
```

How can I convert it into `array([[ 2,  7,  8, 12, 14], [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  9, 10], [0, 1], [11, 13]])`?

I tried `arr.astype(np.int)`, but failed

Comment: You have mixed dimensions, which won't work with numpy. EDIT: well, it will work, but you won't be able to use vectorization. You'd probably be better with lists in that case.

Comment: Related: [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dtype` for an array of arrays will always be `object`. This is unavoidable because with NumPy only non-jagged *n*-dimensional arrays can be held in a contiguous memory block.

Notice your constituent arrays are already of `int` dtype:

```
arr[0].dtype  # dtype('int32')
```

Notice also your logic will work for a *non-jagged* array of arrays:

```
arr = np.array([np.array([ 2,  7,  8]),
                np.array([ 3,  4,  5])], dtype=object)

arr = arr.astype(int)

arr.dtype  # dtype('int32')
```

In fact, in this case, the array of arrays is collapsed into a *single* array:

```
print(arr)

array([[2, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

For computations with a jagged array of arrays you may see *some* performance advantages relative to a list of lists, but the benefit may be limited. See also [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy)