# How to define variable-size numpy array efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for an efficient way to define a variable-size array working with the numpy module, knowing that the performance can be achieved only with the fixed-size arrays.

My solution is to define a list (or tuple) as:

```
test = [0] * 10
```

and then define each element of "test" with a numpy array as:

```
test[0] = numpy.array([1,2,3])
test[1] = numpy.array([4,5])
...
```

I guess this may lead to a scatter memory addressing when using such variable-size array, although vector-computing is maintained for each element of "test" as before.

So, I would appreciate some help, if there is an efficient way around to define such arrays with the numpy module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy)

Comment: Short answer: No.  Long answer: You can try, but you'll get a `dtype = object` array that will have very little utility beyond that of a list.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your comments. I am thinking of treating such problem with 1d memory addressing that may prevent improper memory access but needing additional array for specifying the beginning index of each element in that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create one large allocation behind the scenes, and create a bunch of smaller views:

```
backing = np.empty(10, np.int32)
my_data = [
    backing[0:2],
    backing[2:5],
    backing[5:10]
]

my_data[0][...] = [1, 3]
my_data[1][...] = [1, 3, 5]
my_data[2][...] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
print(my_data)
# [array([1, 3]), array([1, 3, 5]), array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])]
```

This has the nice bonus that you can still operate on the flat array if needed:

```
backing += 1  # add to all sublists
print(my_data)
# [array([2, 4]), array([2, 4, 6]), array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10])]
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. Allocating the total amount of memory at first is a good idea. My question here is whether "my_data" works as a pointer to "backing" numpy array (or it adds extra memory allocation)?

Comment: `my_data` only contains a list of "pointers" to the original array - but pointers need to be allocated too, they're just fixed-size ;)