# Numpy: reshape matrix by blocks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix

```py
[
    [ [1, 2, 3],    [4, 5, 6],    [7, 8, 9],    [10, 11, 12] ],
    [ [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24] ]
]
```

and I want to get

```py
[
    [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18] ],
    [ [19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24] ]
]
```

In this examle block is 2x2x3 size, but it can have XxYx3 size. I've tried different `reshape()` and `transpose()`, the order parameter, but nothing helps

Comment: You ***should not try to do this***.  `numpy` is not meant to store jagged arrays.

Comment: The first is (2,4,3).  What's the second shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in python, because numpy does not support jagged arrays natively. But you can work around this problem by adding null values ​​or using [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) to signal that some indices are invalid in some rows.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916455/9302488) you can find an example to help clarify ideas.