# How can I put together rows with various lengths in in one array or list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some rows like

```
a=[142, 205, 206, 238, 366]
b=[12,14]
c=[1, 5, 8]
```

and I want to put them together in a final array or list with three rows that have different lengths. I used append, concatenate and hstack but all of them need the data have the same dimensions. What can I use please? Thanks

I mean I have a loop that I want to stick lots of rows together (in d) and read every element later from d in another loop based on the column and row of d. I have a big for loop in my code but as an example simply instead of a for consider that I want to do this procedure iteratively like below for only four rows (a,b,c,k) :

```
d=[]

#below are rows of assumed data
a = [142, 205, 206, 238, 366]
b = [12,14]
c = [1, 5, 8]
k=[] #might have null data as well

d=[d,a]
print(d)

d=[d,b]
print(d)

d=[d,k]
print(d)

d=[d,c]
print(d)

d[1][0]
```

But finally this is the answer that I get:

```
[[], [142, 205, 206, 238, 366]]
[[[], [142, 205, 206, 238, 366]], [12, 14]]
[[[[], [142, 205, 206, 238, 366]], [12, 14]], []]
[[[[[], [142, 205, 206, 238, 366]], [12, 14]], []], [1, 5, 8]]

1
```

which is not right and it should be d[1][0]=142

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for a way to put `a`, `b` and `c` in an array? (so the combined array is 2 dimensional)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say that "_all of them need ... the same dimensions_". Can you provide an example of what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Are these numpy arrays or lists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy)

Comment: I edited my post. Please see thanks

Comment: @zeinab I don't really understand what's different about your new code. You state 'I have a big for loop in my code but as an example simply instead...', could you share the full code, or at least more of it? It'll be much easier to find a good solution once we actually know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does not support jagged arrays, so your best option is a list.

```py
a = [142, 205, 206, 238, 366]
b = [12,14]
c = [1, 5, 8]

d = [a, b, c]
```

I'm still not entirely sure I understand your edit, but tell me if this example seems like what you're looking for:

```py
combined_list = []

print(combined_list)

list_1 = [14, 17, 12, 16, 18, 0, 9, 11, 8,  5]
combined_list.append(list_1)
print(combined_list)

list_2 = [12, 9, 11, 4, 5]
combined_list.append(list_2)
print(combined_list)

list_3 = [2, 14, 7]
combined_list.append(list_3)
print(combined_list)

list_4 = [4, 2, 17, 9, 9, 11, 15, 14, 14]
combined_list.append(list_4)
print(combined_list)
```

Comment: @zeinab I edited my answer, tell me what you think :)

Answer (score -1):

```
d = [a,b,c] will put them in a list of lists
```

to make it into an array:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(d)
```