# How to use numba to accelerate a numpy.ndarray with vectors in diffrerent dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, numba, dimensions

```
@jit
def f_(path,stack,idx):
    res = []
    l = len(path)
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(i+1,l):

            ### combine vector for union and intersection
            path_combine = np.hstack((path[i],path[j]))
            stack_combine = np.hstack((stack[i],stack[j]))
            stack_sort = np.sort(stack_combine)
            stack_diff = np.diff(stack_sort)
            used_idx = np.where(stack_diff==0)[0]

            ### if not path.intersection and stack.intersection
            if np.unique(path_combine).shape[0]==path_combine.shape[0] and \
            len(used_idx) !=0:

                for ele in stack_combine[used_idx]:
                    res.append(np.hstack((path_combine,np.array([ele],np.float64),idx)))
    return res

path  = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,9],[4,6,7],...,[6,7,14]] 
### the vectors in stack have different dimension, as follows
### len(path)==len(stack)
stack = [[1,2],[3,4,5,6,7,8],[4],...,[3,4,6,8,91]]

idx = np.array([0],np.float64)
res =  f_(path,stack,idx)
```

The list was not accepted by numba, but these vectors can not be transformed to a homogeneous matrix. How can i use numba to accelerate vectors with different dimensions?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably can't. Like Numpy, Numba is not accepting "jagged arrays".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy)

Comment: thanks for your answers, i gave up using numba. it is troublesome.