# How to make 2D jagged array using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d

I want to make a 2D array that in the first row has 2 elements, in the second row has 4 elements, and in the third row has 6. Below is my code:

```
jagged_array = np.array([
[None, None], 
[None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None]
])
print(jagged_array)
print(jagged_array.ndim)
print(jagged_array.shape)
```

However, the output doesn't look right. And the dimension is 1 (I expected 2). Here is the output:

```
[list([None, None]) list([None, None, None, None])
 list([None, None, None, None, None, None])]
1
(3,)
```

I want to know how I can make a 2D array with each row having different number of columns.

Comment: You can't.  This is a 1d array containing lists; more like a list of lists.  But what do you expect to do with such an array?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy) answer:

> NumPy does not support jagged arrays natively. gives an array that may or may not behave as you expect.

A workaround using [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html) can be as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

a = np.array([0, 1])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])
c = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])

jagged_array = ma.vstack(
    [
        ma.array(np.resize(a, c.shape[0]), mask=[False, False, True, True, True, True]),
        ma.array(
            np.resize(b, c.shape[0]), mask=[False, False, False, False, True, True]
        ),
        c,
    ]
)
print(jagged_array)
print(jagged_array.ndim)
print(jagged_array.shape)
```

Your output would look like:

```py
❯ python3 sample.py
[[0 1 -- -- -- --]
 [2 3 4 5 -- --]
 [6 7 8 9 10 11]]
2
(3, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ndim(arr):
    return len(arr)-1
jagged_array = np.array([[None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None,None, None, None]])
print(jagged_array)
print(ndim(jagged_array))
print(jagged_array.shape)
```