# NumPy Get elements based on starting indices and stride

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am looking for the numpythonic way to accomplish the following:

```
A = np.arange(1000)
x = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30], dtype=int)
dx = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int)

for x_, dx_ in zip(x, dx):
    print(A[x_:x_+dx_])
```

Looking at [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920850/how-can-i-extract-multiple-random-sub-sequences-from-a-numpy-array?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the [as_strided documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) it doesn't seem like I can provide varying stride/window lengths. Is there a pure numpy way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think so. In order to create a single array with all of the values, NumPy would need to support jagged arrays, [which it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165451/how-to-make-2d-jagged-array-using-numpy). There could maybe be a solution that gives you a list of arrays, though at that point I'm not sure how much faster than a pure-python solution it would be.

Comment: With `A[x_:x_+dx_]` you can get a list of `view` (each indexing is basic, sliced, indexing.  Since they vary in length they can't be combined into one 2d array.  Usually the alternatives create some sort of index array, `advanced indexing` and hence a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NickOdell pointed out, Numpy does not support jagged arrays. However if you can afford to waste some memory, there are workarounds. For example you could use `np.nan` as a fill value:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(1000)
x = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30], dtype=int)
dx = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int)

A_padded = np.append(A, np.nan)

idx = x[:, np.newaxis] + np.arange(max(dx))
idx = np.where(idx >= (x + dx)[:, np.newaxis], -1, idx)

print(A_padded[idx])
```

Which prints:

```
[[ 0.  1.  2. nan nan nan]
 [10. 11. 12. 13. nan nan]
 [20. 21. 22. 23. 24. nan]
 [30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 35.]]
```

Whether this is a valid workaround depends on your context.

Otherwise you might want to take a look at https://awkward-array.org, which supports jagged arrays.

I hope this helps!