# Create a new array out of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a new array out of two other arrays. I already tried multiple np.append() statements along multiple axis. Here is some code:

```
arr1 = np.zeros(2, 3)
arr2 = np.zeros(2, 2)
new_arr = np.append(arr1, arr2)
print(new_arr)
```

Desired output:

```
[
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
]
```

Actual output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy)

Comment: Do you want to have the 2*2 array in the same line as 2*3 array or in the other line?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([0, 0, 0])

arr2 = np.array([0, 0, 0])

final_arr = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2))

print(final_arr)
```

Refer this --> https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: That only works if both arrays have the same shape. Otherwise you get the following: ```ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 2```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
np.asarray([list(arr1),list(arr2)], dtype = 'O')
```

The `dtype = 'O'` means `Object` type.

Comment: Why is it so complicated? Why does numpy append arrays so wierdly?

Comment: @melonmarlon because it isn't made to work this way. From the docs: "An array object represents a multidimensional, homogeneous array of fixed-size items" (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)