# How do I vstack or concatenate matricies of different shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, vstack

In a situation like the one below, how do I vstack the two matrices?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]])
b = np.array([[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]])

a = np.vstack([a, b])

Output:   
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 2
```

The output I would like would look like this:

```
a = array([[[3, 3, 3],
            [3, 3, 3],
            [3, 3, 3]],
           [[2, 2],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 2]]])
```

My goal is to then to loop over the content of the stacked matrices, index each matrix and call a function on a specific row.

```
for matrix in a:
   row = matrix[1]
   print(row)

Output: 
[3, 3, 3]
[2, 2]
```

Comment: What is your desired output of the operation?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy) answer your question?

Comment: Explain what you expect from a (3,3) and (3,2)

Comment: I have added a more comprehensive explanation including my desired output.

Comment: For that iteration just use a list, `for matrix in [a,b]:`.  Making a numpy array from the two arrays is not going to help you!  It's impossible to create the combined array that you show.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with those "Numpy is faster" claims.  If you already have arrays, and make full use of array methods, `numpy` is indeed faster.  But if you start with lists, or have to use Python level iteration (as you do in `Pack...`), the `numpy` version might well be slower.

Just doing a time test on the `Pack` step:

```
In [12]: timeit Pack_Matrices_with_NaN([a,b,c],5)
221 µs ± 9.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Compare that with fetching the first row of each array with a simple list comprehension:

```
In [13]: [row[1] for row in [a,b,c]]
Out[13]: [array([3., 3., 3.]), array([2., 2.]), array([4., 4., 4., 4.])]
In [14]: timeit [row[1] for row in [a,b,c]]
808 ns ± 2.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

200 µs compared to less than 1 µs!

And timing your `Unpack`:

```
In [21]: [Unpack_Matrix_with_NaN(packed_matrices.reshape(3,3,5),i)[1,:] for i in range(3)]
    ...: 
Out[21]: [array([3., 3., 3.]), array([2., 2.]), array([4., 4., 4., 4.])]
In [22]: timeit [Unpack_Matrix_with_NaN(packed_matrices.reshape(3,3,5),i)[1,:] for i in ra
    ...: nge(3)]
199 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this only using NumPy. As NumPy is significantly faster than python's list function (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-fast-numpy-really-is-e9111df44347) I wanted to share my answer as it might be useful to others.

I started with adding np.NaN to make the two arrays the same shape.

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]).astype(float)
b = np.array([[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]]).astype(float)

# Extend each vector in array with Nan to reach same shape
b = np.insert(b, 2, np.nan, axis=1)

# Now vstack the arrays 
a = np.vstack([[a], [b]])
print(a)

Output: 
[[[ 3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.]]

 [[ 2.  2. nan]
  [ 2.  2. nan]
  [ 2.  2. nan]]]
```

Then I wrote a function to unpack each array in a, and remove the nan.

```
def Unpack_Matrix_with_NaN(Matrix_with_nan, matrix_of_interest):
    for first_row in Matrix_with_nan[matrix_of_interest,:1]:
        # find shape of matrix row without nan 
        first_row_without_nan = first_row[~np.isnan(first_row)]
        shape = first_row_without_nan.shape[0]
        matrix_without_nan = np.arange(shape)
        for row in Matrix_with_nan[matrix_of_interest]:
            row_without_nan = row[~np.isnan(row)]
            matrix_without_nan = np.vstack([matrix_without_nan, row_without_nan])
        # Remove vector specifying shape 
        matrix_without_nan = matrix_without_nan[1:]
        return matrix_without_nan
```

I could then loop through the matrices, find my desired row, and print it.

```
Matrix_with_nan = a

for matrix in range(len(Matrix_with_nan)):
    matrix_of_interest = Unpack_Matrix_with_NaN(a, matrix)
    row = matrix_of_interest[1]
    print(row)

Output: 
[3. 3. 3.]
[2. 2.]
```

I also made a function to pack matrices when more than one nan needs to be added per row:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]).astype(float)
b = np.array([[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]]).astype(float)
c = np.array([[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]]).astype(float)

# Extend each vector in array with Nan to reach same shape
def Pack_Matrices_with_NaN(List_of_matrices, Matrix_size):
    Matrix_with_nan = np.arange(Matrix_size)
    for array in List_of_matrices:
        start_position = len(array[0])
        for x in range(start_position,Matrix_size):
            array = np.insert(array, (x), np.nan, axis=1)
        Matrix_with_nan = np.vstack([Matrix_with_nan, array])
    Matrix_with_nan = Matrix_with_nan[1:]
    return Matrix_with_nan

arrays = [a,b,c]
packed_matrices = Pack_Matrices_with_NaN(arrays, 5)
print(packed_matrices) 

Output:
[[ 3.  3.  3. nan nan]
 [ 3.  3.  3. nan nan]
 [ 3.  3.  3. nan nan]
 [ 2.  2. nan nan nan]
 [ 2.  2. nan nan nan]
 [ 2.  2. nan nan nan]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4. nan]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4. nan]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4. nan]]
```