# lambda function for slicing a numpy array to specific index and reshape it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to slice a numpy array with its index and reshape that with one-liner lambda function. Let me explain with minimal producible example:

This is my numpy array.

```py
In [1]: composite                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1]: 
array([ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  3,
       -1,  3,  1,  3,  1,  1,  3,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  3,  1,  1,  1, -1,
        1,  1, -3, -3, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1, -1,  1, -3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -3,
       -1, -3,  1, -1, -3, -1, -3, -1, -1, -1, -3, -3, -3, -1, -3, -3,  1,
        1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -3,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -3,
       -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  3,
        3,  1,  3,  3,  1,  1,  3, -1,  3, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  3,
        1,  3,  3, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,
        1, -1, -1,  1, -3,  1, -3, -1, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1,
       -3, -1, -3, -3, -1, -3, -3,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -3,  1,
       -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -3, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1,
       -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -3,  1,
       -3, -1, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -3, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  3, -1,  3,  1,  3,
        1,  1,  3,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  3,  1])
```

I want to slice every 32 element in the array and make them as one element in array, something like this:

```py
# I know i used composite[:32] and get below
array([ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  3,
       -1,  3,  1,  3,  1,  1,  3,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  3,  1,  1])
```

This is just an example but the actual length of the array is unknown in my case so i don't know how big my array is going to be. But i want something like this:

```py
# I know i used composite[:32] and get below
array([ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  3,
       -1,  3,  1,  3,  1,  1,  3,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  3,  1,  1],
      [-1,  1,  1, -3, -3, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1, -1,  1, -3, -1, -1, 
      -1, -1,-3, -1, -3,  1, -1, -3, -1, -3, -1, -1, -1, -3, -3, -3], ... and so
      on...till the end of the array))
```

Is there an intelligent way of doing this ? Perhaps a lambda function ?

presently i am manually doing it using below function.

```py
def de_repeater(seq, size):
    chunks = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(seq):
        #print(list(seq[index:index+size]))
        #print(len(list(seq[index:index+size])))
        chunks.append(list(seq[index:index+size]))
        index+=size

    bits = []
    for List in chunks:
        #print(max(set(List), key = List.count)) 
        bits.append(max(set(List), key = List.count))

    return bits
a1 = de_repeater(composite, 8)
len(a1) #31
```

Comment: is the expected output a list of arrays? or can it be a list of lists? I'm assuming you want a list, otherwise `reshape` should work, no?

Comment: Is the length of the array a multiple of 32? You'd need to otherwise have to deal with [ragged arrays in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916455/17769815), which might not be a good idea.

Comment: @enke -- I think he wants an `ndarray` if you take a close look at the expected output.

Comment: I need `ndarray` and it would always be in the multiple of 2(I mean yes the length would be a multiple of 32).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.reshape()` if you know that the length of the array is a multiple of 32 (as described in a comment):

```py
np.reshape(composite, (-1, 32))
```

If you pad the original `composite` array with eight ones, you'll get:

```py
[[ 1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  3 -1  3  1  3  1  1  3
   1 -1  1 -1 -1  3  1  1]
 [ 1 -1  1  1 -3 -3 -3 -1 -1 -3 -1 -1  1 -3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -3 -1 -3  1 -1 -3
  -1 -3 -1 -1 -1 -3 -3 -3]
 [-1 -3 -3  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -3  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -3 -1  1 -1
   1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  3]
 [ 1  1  1  1  1  3  3  1  3  3  1  1  3 -1  3 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  3  1
   3  3 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -3  1 -3 -1 -3 -1 -1 -3 -1  1 -1  1
   1 -3 -1 -3 -3 -1 -3 -3]
 [ 1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -3  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -3 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1
  -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -3  1 -3 -1 -3 -1 -1 -3 -1  1 -1  1  1 -3
  -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1]
 [ 1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  3 -1  3  1  3  1  1  3  1 -1  1 -1 -1  3  1
   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]]
```

Comment: It's giving me error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 248 into shape (32)`.

Comment: 248 is not a multiple of 32, but the comment states that such an assumption can be made. Pad the array with eight ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `round(len(composite)/32)` instead of hardcoding `32` to prevent any errors. As you can see `composite` is having 248 elements, and hardcoding `32` might cause a problem. So, rounding might help but this will cause the subarrays to be of `length < 32`(only if the length is not a multiple of `32`. It works fine for multiples of `32`):

```
size = round(len(composite)/32) # 8
composite = composite.reshape((size,-1))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,
         3, -1,  3,  1,  3,  1,  1,  3,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  3,  1],
       [ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -3, -3, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1, -1,  1, -3, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -3, -1, -3,  1, -1, -3, -1, -3, -1, -1, -1, -3],
       [-3, -3, -1, -3, -3,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -3,  1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -3, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  1,  1,  3,
        -1,  3, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  3,  1,  3,  3, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,
        -3,  1, -3, -1, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -3, -1],
       [-3, -3, -1, -3, -3,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -3,  1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -3, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,
        -3,  1, -3, -1, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -3, -1],
       [ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,
         3, -1,  3,  1,  3,  1,  1,  3,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  3,  1]])
```