# how to remove some of one array's elements according to other array's value in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy,

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
b = np.array([[5, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0]])
```

I want to remove some of `b`'s elements according to `a`'s values. I want to keep the elements of `b` only when the value of `a`'s matching elements is 1, and discard the other elements of `b`.
In this example what I want is:

```
>>> [[1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 5]]
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: Will `a`’s values always guarantee a valid shape of `b`? See [How do I stack vectors of different lengths in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916407/how-do-i-stack-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-numpy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask to index into `b` and finally reshape the result.

```py
res = b[a == 1].reshape(a.shape[0], -1)
print(res)
```

Or

```py
res = [list(np.array(b_row)[a_row == 1]) for a_row, b_row in zip(a, b)]
print(res)
```

---

```
[[1 0 2]
 [0 1 5]]
```

Comment: What if the number of elements with a value of 1 is different each time? It's not always same 3.

Comment: I made an update

Comment: Your solution was the easiest to understand, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the next line:

```
result = b[a == 1].reshape((2, 3))
```

**Update**
In case of dynamic amount of `ones` you can use the next code:

```
mask = a == 1
result = [b_row[mask_row] for b_row, mask_row in zip(b, mask)]
```

or

```
result = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    mask = a[i] == 1
    result.append(b[i][mask].tolist())
```

Comment: What if the number of elements with a value of 1 is different each time? It's not always same 3.

Comment: @JuneYoon, the only one condition for these solutions is that the amount of integers in each list of the list `a` must be the same, i.e. the shape.

Answer (score 1):

considering `What if the number of elements with a value of 1 is different each time? It's not always same 3.`

maybe that's sufficient solution:

```py
result = [
    [
        element_b
        for element_a, element_b in zip(list_a, list_b)
        if element_a == 1
    ]
    for list_a, list_b in zip(a,b)
]
```