# How to add arrays inside a numpy array without flattening

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([112,123,134,145])
>>> b = np.array([212,223,234])
>>> c = np.array([312,323])
>>> d = np.array([412])

>>> arr = np.hstack([a,b,c,d])
>>> arr
array([112, 123, 134, 145, 212, 223, 234, 312, 323, 412])

>>> arr = np.array([a,b,c,d])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.
>>>
```

Expected array -

```
array([[112,123,134,145], [212,223,234], [312,323], [412]],
      [[512,523,534,545], [612,623,634], [712,723], [812]], ...)
```

Comment: It can be done with numpy dtype object, but then you will be using numpy for something it was not designed for which is storing non homogenious data. I would recumbent simply to create 4 arrays to store data by its number of columns.

Comment: As stated above, there's nothing in `numpy` that will be useful for manipulating "ragged" (non-rectangular) arrays, and creating the `dtype=object` arrays that will kinda let you do it anyway is a gateway to insanity once you start trying to debug `numpy` functions that only barely work with objects, if they do at all.  Use a linked list, or a list of rectangular arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that isn't working for you, because it works for me with no problems and what you did is a common approach for this kind of situation (another example of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916455/11766335)).

Another similar approach you could try (that is not particularly efficient but may get the job done) is just appending a blank list like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([112,123,134,145])
b = np.array([212,223,234])
c = np.array([312,323])
d = np.array([412])
e = []
for sublist in [a,b,c,d]: 
    e.append(list(sublist)) #include the list cast to get the expected result you mentioned 
 e = np.array(e)
```

Honestly, it seems strange that what you did didn't work but I hope this helps to provide at least another option.

I should note that I did come across a library that is dedicated to working with nested variable-sized data called [Awkward Array](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward#readme)

Comment: Isn't that `e` just `[a,b,c,d]`?

Comment: yup. pretty much, minus the casting. note, as i mentioned, the OP's answer 'arr = np.array([a,b,c,d])' works for me, no problem. So suggesting a slightly alternate approach. Using a loop, maybe the OP can pinpoint where things get funky.

Comment: What numpy version are you using?  The OP has a recent one that raises this error.  Your's looks like an older one that automatically used object dtype.

Comment: Ahh, good point. Maybe that's why I can't reproduce the error. I'm using '1.23.3'

Comment: I do need to have the final large array as an numpy array rather than a list since I need to do more further statistics on the array

Answer (score 0):

The `numpy.hstack()` function can be used to join two or more arrays along the horizontal axis. However, this function will flatten the arrays before joining them.
so you can use this instead:

```
import numpy as np

a = [112, 123, 134, 145]
b = [212, 223, 234]
c = [312, 323]
d = [412]


# Create a list of lists
list_of_lists = [a, b, c, d]

arr = np.empty(len(list_of_lists), dtype=object)
arr[:] = list_of_lists

print(arr)
```

Comment: How's that any different from `np.array([a,b,c,d])`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `object` dtype when trying to make a "ragged" array:

```
In [24]: >>> a = np.array([112,123,134,145])
    ...: >>> b = np.array([212,223,234])
    ...: >>> c = np.array([312,323])
    ...: >>> d = np.array([412])
In [25]: arr = np.array([a,b,c,d], dtype=object)
In [26]: arr
Out[26]: 
array([array([112, 123, 134, 145]), array([212, 223, 234]),
       array([312, 323]), array([412])], dtype=object)
```

Keep in mind that such an array is little better, maybe worse, that the simple list of arrays.

The error message you get without `object` dtype, has varied over versions.  It used be automatic, then you got a warning, and then an error message.  Now you get this error.  Clearly, such an array is "sub-optimal" from a numeric array standpoint.

For some shapes you have to start with a `arr = np.empty(4, object)`, and insert the arrays from a list.

```
In [27]: arr = np.empty(4,object); arr[:] = [a,b,c,d]
In [28]: arr
Out[28]: 
array([array([112, 123, 134, 145]), array([212, 223, 234]),
       array([312, 323]), array([412])], dtype=object)
In [29]: arr = np.empty(4,object); arr[:] = [i.tolist() for i in [a,b,c,d]]
In [30]: arr
Out[30]: 
array([list([112, 123, 134, 145]), list([212, 223, 234]),
       list([312, 323]), list([412])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `>>> arr = np.array([a,b,c,d], dtype=object)
>>> arr
array([array([112, 123, 134, 145]), array([212, 223, 234]),
       array([312, 323]), array([412])], dtype=object)
>>> arr.ndim
1
>>> arr = np.array([[a,b,c,d]], dtype=object)
>>> arr.ndim
2
>>> ` 
I put it in additional square brackets to make it 2D. Then after appending another array, it gets flattened.

Comment: `>>> arr = np.append(arr, np.array([[a,b,c,d]], dtype=object))
>>> arr
array([array([112, 123, 134, 145]), array([212, 223, 234]),
       array([312, 323]), array([412]), array([112, 123, 134, 145]),
       array([212, 223, 234]), array([312, 323]), array([412])],
      dtype=object)
>>> arr[1]
array([212, 223, 234])
>>> arr.ndim
1
>>> `

Comment: Why do you want a `(1,4)` shape?  And don't use `np.append` - at least not without actually reading its docs.